# Connecting 2 routers, cannot connect to the second one via wifi

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dhcp

Okay here is my setup:

- My main Router IP is 192.168.1.1 the DHCP range is 192.168.1.2 - 192.168.1.100
- I factory reseted the Router 2
- At Router 2 I set its static IP to be 192.168.1.101
- At Router 2 I disabled all DHCP
- I connected the 2 routers via LAN
- Now when I connect to my main router's wifi I can access the second router at 192.168.1.101
- Now when I connect my PC to Router 2 via LAN cable I have internet and everything is fine
- The problem is when I try to connect with wifi to Router 2

  a) On my phone it just stops at "Optaining IP Address" and cannot continue

  b) My Laptop cannot connect also
- I change the "Channel Width" of Router 2 from 20MHz to "Auto" (as it is on Router 1)
- Now the devices can connect to the router BUT there is no internet and ALSO the IP address of the laptop is 192.168.1.102 which is WTF since that's out of the range of the DHCP of the Main Router and Router 2 has DHCP Disabled... Also its (the laptop's) Default gateway is 192.168.1.101 and I expect it to be 192.168.1.1 (as the Main Router)

Can someone help me debug this problem? I am attaching some screenshots of the setups:

1) Main Router WLAN Settings
[image: Main Router WLAN Settings]

2) Router 2 DHCP Settings
[image: Router 2 DHCP Settings]

3) Router 2 WLAN Settings
[image]

4) Running `ipconfig` on the laptop connected with wifi to router 2
[image]

As text:

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek RTL8822BE 802.11ac PCIe Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 0C-96-E6-17-6F-83
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.102(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, December 10, 2019 2:58:11 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Friday, December 13, 2019 11:50:31 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.101
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.101
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.101
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

Does anyone have any ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: Set Router2 to bridge mode. Connect it to Router1 via WAN interface.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but Router 2 Does not have WAN port, it has only Optical, LAN, and TEL1/2 ports :/ ( I don't know if that is even possible but I just can't find the WAN port)

Comment: I don'd understand your scheme. Where internet is coming from and what it is connected to? *and ALSO the IP address of the laptop is 192.168.1.102 which is WTF since* `ipconfig` does NOT show that DHCP is used. Execute `ipconfig /all`. And also `route print`. And show as text, not as a screenshot.

Comment: The Internet is coming from the Main Router, It is connected and configured from my Internet Service Company and works as expected, I wanted to connect a 2nd router via LAN so I can connect to Router 2 via Wifi and use the internet that is coming from Router 1

Comment: I also added the requested command as text to the question.

Comment: Please disable IPv6 on the interface and get IPCONFIG /ALL again (the lines relative to connected WiFi interface only, from "Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:" till "NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled"). And look on "Security" - maybe you'll find something about "WLAN isolated" or similar?

Comment: I disabled ipv6 and ran the command and the output is at the question again. It is interesting that it shows the DHCP server as the IP of Router 2 and I'm guessing there is the problem I have to find a way to disable this for sure even though I did it through the interface. Where you want me to look in "Security"? I didn't find anything for WLAN isolated on any of the routers.

Comment: Router2's DHCP is disabled. Nevertheless it works and leases addresses, and I don't know why... and Huawei documentation tells nothing. I don't know how to help you.